# What is the relationship between the man and the woman?

Tags: situation, family

> A man walks up to a house and knocks on the door.
>   He hears a woman asking: "Who is it?"
>   The man answers: "My mother-in-law and your mother-in-law are mother and daughter"

What is the relationship between the man and the woman?

Comment: _"A riddle gives indirect clues about an unnamed object or concept to be identified. It is often presented in the form of a poem."_ I still don't think that applies to this question...

Comment: @Wu33o The riddle tag is often misapplied. Just edit it out :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answer:

> The man can be the girl's father-in-law.

But:

> The man can also be the girl's mother-in-law's brother-in-law. (try saying this 3 times out loud)

Let's make this notations:

M - the man
G - the girl
MML - man's mother-in-law
GML - girl's mother-in-law.

We get this:

> ```
>                        MML
>
>                        /\
>
>       mother- daughter/  \ mother-in-law - son-in-law
>
>                      /    \
>
>                    GML     M
>
>                     |
>
>      Mother-IL-Daugher-IL
>
>                     |
>
>                     G
> ```

From this tree we can deduce that

> M is the husband of GML hence his is the girl's father-in-law.
>  Or GML has a sister or brother and M is married to that brother or sister.

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

> Man is father-in-Law of the girl

If Daughter's mother-in-law is man's wife, so that man's mother-in-law is his wife's Mother. So in relation Man is father-in-law of the girl.

Answer (score 2):

The woman could also be

> The man's mother-in-law, because she is married to his spouse's mother

Comment: Ah, the 21st century, politically correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The key statement is,
“My mother-in-law and your mother-in-law are mother and daughter.” 
Note that this statement omits the critical word, ***respectively***,
so the order of the two lists is not necessarily the same. 
The accepted answer assumes that the mother-in-law of the man (who knocked)
is ***the mother of*** the mother-in-law of the girl/woman/female
who was inside the house. 
But it’s possible, *as in [Dane Andersen’s answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/40023/19765#40069)*,
that the mother-in-law of the man (who knocked) is ***the daughter of***
the mother-in-law of the girl/woman/female who was inside the house. 
This leads us to the following family tree (where “=” represents marriage,
and “/”, “|” and “\” represent parent-child relationships). 
Let M<sub>0</sub> and F<sub>0</sub> represent the man and the female
who speak in the riddle (***respectively***).

> ```
>        F3
>       / \
>      F2  M4 = F0
>      |
> M0 = F1
> ```

i.e., the man could be

> the son-in-law of the woman’s sister-in-law.

Answer (score -1):

> The widower married a woman whose widowed mother married the widower's son.

Answer (score -2):

I see other answers are very intricate, but in the fact the answer is simple:

If I use this notations:

M - the man
G - the girl

> G is M Aunt.
>   I mean G is M.Mother sister.
>
> So
>
> G.mother and M.mother are mother and daughter.

I'm confused with accepted answer really !

Comment: I think this would only be possible if the man and the woman (his aunt) were married.

Comment: You've completely ignored the mother-in-law relationships.

Comment: True answer is clear for me, because this is an old and public Persian mystery. however maybe here people think the answer must be intricate.